# Set target branch for non-tracking remote

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push

I have a web-app deployed on heroku. In order to update the running instance, I must `git push` my code to the `master` branch of the heroku remote.

I also keep my code on github, and have github as my `origin` and upstream repository. I'm trying a slightly new workflow, and therefore my local-and-github `master` branch contains the latest stable version I'm working on locally; while a local-and-github `release` branch contains the code which is actually running on heroku.

Given all that, my workflow currently looks like this:

```
$ git checkout master
... make some changes ...
$ git commit
$ git push                # to origin/master - that is, github
$ git checkout release
$ git merge master
$ git push heroku master  # Push the release branch to heroku's master branch, thereby sending it live.
```

I would like to avoid having to type `master` after the `git push heroku` line each time. I will never want to push to anything other than `master` on `heroku`. Is it possible to change my git config so that pushes to `heroku` of the local `release` branch update the `master` branch on `heroku`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a custom refspec to the configuation and denoting the topic branch `release` being assigned to the destination's remote branch of `master` will perform the desired `git push heroku` action.

`git config --add remote.heroku.push refs/heads/release:refs/heads/master`

In other words, the refspec is saying for any push to this remote:

1. The source branch (local) is the `release` branch
2. The destination branch (remote) is `master` branch
3. Always transmit `release` commits to `master` on this remote

More about customizing refspecs is [available here](http://git-scm.com/book/ch9-5.html).

Answer (score 0):

git 1.8:

`git branch --set-upstream-to=heroku/master release`

git 1.7:

`git branch --set-upstream release heroku/master`

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think this is what I want. I want `git push` and `git pull` to still refer to `origin`; but I want `git push heroku` to target the `master` branch on the heroku remote.